# Как изменить определенный текст в TextView

Tags: android, android-textview, span

Есть TextView, в ней нужно выделить определенные слова цветом текста, цветом и формой заднего фона. Пробовал сделать с помощью Html, нет тегов, которые скругляют фон. Пробовал с различными Span-ами. BackgroundColorSpan не дает менять форму. TextAppearanceSpan делает все что угодно с текстом, но не с фоном. ImageSpan просто добавляет картинку, на нее нельзя добавить текст. Выделенные слова должны выделяться и быть кликабельными. Возможно есть какой-то Span, которому на задний фон можно подать не цвет а drawable ресурс. Или как-то можно расширить доступные Html теги.

[image: Должно выглядеть так]

Comment: [Ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24701762/android-spannablecontent-with-rounded-corners)

Comment: @Style-7 спасибо, сработало

Answer (score 0):

В XML разметке ты это сделать не сможешь, только если разделить текст на несколько TextView.

Но можешь попробовать такой способ.

```
TextView TV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytextview);

Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString("Твой текст");        

wordtoSpan.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 15, 30, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

TV.setText(wordtoSpan);
```

Вместо 15 и 30 ставишь откуда начать закрашивать и где закончить.

В любом случае это не готовое решение, а просто вариант решения.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать добиться нужного эффекта с помощью Flow, просто добавляйте background тем textView, которые хотите выделить. высоту flow задайте wrap_content для автоматического переноса элементов на следующую строку, a у textView установите атрибут lines = 1

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="tv1, tv2, tv3"
        app:flow_firstHorizontalStyle="packed"
        app:flow_wrapMode="chain2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lines="1"
        android:text="Молоко пастеризованное, "
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:lines="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/red_square"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="E282"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lines="1"
        android:text=" закваска"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
```

С настройками нужно еще конечно поиграться, но вот что навскидку получилось у меня:
https:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4O69J.jpg